# Changing URL structure through .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know that apache .htaccess files are capable of rewriting URLs and making them more readable  and efficient, but I don't know how to achieve this.

Lets say I have these kinds of URLs:

```
http://mywebsite.com/index.php?mode=home
http://mywebsite.com/index.php?mode=articles
http://mywebsite.com/index.php?mode=about
```

But I want these to look nicer and readable. Something like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/home
http://mywebsite.com/articles
http://mywebsite.com/about
```

This seems like a complex task for an apache novice like myself.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: duplicate of so many other questions, it hurts to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [QSA,L]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)